# cell navigation doesn't work in the TEXTVIEW area

Tags: ios, swift, textview, storyboard

I created tableView with cell in StoryBoard.
Then after adding segue for navigation Controller in next view all area is working fine except textView.
I didnt find any information why it work so

[image]

This is my controller

```
import UIKit

class RoutesViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePick: UITextField!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    let date = Date()
    let routes = Route.manyRoutes
    let temp = Int.random(in: 10...100)
    //formatter.
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
        datePick.text = formatter.string(from: date)
        //datePick.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 5
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell
        let route = routes[indexPath.row]
        cell.routeDescription.text = route.text
        cell.routeNumber.text = String(indexPath.row + temp)
        cell.routeOptions.text = "\(route.length) км, \(route.time) мин"
        return cell
    }
}
```

and screen from simulator

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to print on your view when you run it ?
textfield.text is empty ?

Comment: no I fill textView with text

Comment: can you share your codes rather than images

Comment: It's unclear what's happening. Define "not working", text is empty? How did you set the text? Or cell is too small and textview is "too compressed, like hidden"?

Comment: the text is shown, but when you click on it, the transition is not performed, there is no such problem with the image and label

Comment: Try disabling the user interaction for the textView `textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: its helpfull thanks! but now when tapping in area, cell change color on selected, textView is not

Comment: @ИскандерНизамов remove the textView background color `textView.backgroundColor = nil`

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
textView.background= nil
```

Answer (score 0):

The textView is capturing the click/tap event, you need to disable the user interaction on the textView to allow the cell to handle it:

```
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

To avoid a different background color between the cell and textView on tap, remove the textView background color

```
textView.background = nil
```